# Mongoose property accepts values other than the enum

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose model. I set an enum for status, but status still accepts any value other than the enum. What an I doing wrong here? When I typed ABCDEF as the value, still it is saved in the mongodb.

```
 import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
    import Joi from '@hapi/joi';

    import { USER_STATUSES } from 'enums';

    const userSchema = new Schema({
      firstName: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 20,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 20,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50, 
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      mobile: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 255,
        required: true,
      },
      status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Pending', 'Active'],
        default: 'ABCDEF,
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    });

    export default model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: Firstly you should export your user model like this: module.exports = model('User', userSchema);  Secondly how do you save user, can you add code to then question?

Comment: Why don't you add 'ABCDEF' to your enum like this:  enum: ['Pending', 'Active', 'ABCDEF'], ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a default and create a new document, it could be that there is no validation in the beginning. You can try doing:

```js
userSchema.pre('save', function (doc) {
  if (!acceptedValues.includes(doc.status)) {
    // error handling
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When **updating** a document, you should enable validation using the option { runValidators: true }. It is disabled by default. According to the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators):

> Be careful: update validators are off by default because they have
> several caveats.

In a router, it should look something like this:

```
        const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            editedUser,
            {runValidators: true, returnOriginal: false, useFindAndModify: false}
        )
```